# installing clockworkmod in Huawei u8150

Tags: android, recovery, rom

I installed clockworkmod recovery in mu Huawei u8150 phone using ROM Manager. But when I reboot in to recovery mod using ROM Manager(or pressing power, volume down and call end buttons), it stay on the starting display and nothing happens. Can I know what's wrong with this and how to install clockworkmod recovery to my phone? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is not suitable for Stackoverflow it should be on [Android Stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you flashed CWM 3.0.2.4 which is for the newer roms just change the recovery mod to the traditional one and then reboot into recovery mod and I think from that you will be on a safer way